# Cakephp MySQL database table column name

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Is there a way to bypass the column names ending with "_id" and just use this as column name for the current table without creating relationship with other tables?
I want to create a model without linking to any other table but maintain column name ending with "_id".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't specify the relationship in the models.